# Capture string only on exact matching with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, url

I'm trying to capture a string only when the matching is exact.

I.e.valid:

```
/this-is-an-exact-matc
/this-is-also-an-exact-match
/this-is-other-exact-match?d=1
/balbabla
```

Not valid:

```
/this-is-not/fafa/fafa
/dede/ddd/dfsfd
/
```

As you can just one path level must count as a valid string.
I was trying with:

```
\/(.*)
```

... but this is also validating to true something like /bbalbalb/blablba

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this:

```
string =~ %r{\A/[^/]+\z}
```

To get what you asked in the comment, try this:

```
string[%r{(?<=\A/)(?=[^/]+\z)([^?]+)}]
```

Comment: thanks, just a question more: I used \A\/([^\/]+)\z to fetch all but /. Given "/dad?var=1", how could I only fetch "dad" ?

Comment: @ratamaster why you need `regex` to do this test. Why not non-regex solution?

Comment: @ratamaster Do you care if a slash appears after `?`?

Comment: @Priti because regex is smarter ? Actually I could solve this splting by "/" but I just want to try something more interesting.

Comment: @ratamaster I am not strong on Regex,and when I will be having some direct function to solve,I would personally avoid `regex`,because `regex` are fast,and if not taken care properly,its dangerous too. Your choice how would you go.... :)

Comment: @sawa yes I do, this shouldn't match: /dad?var=1/mom

Answer (score 0):

```
  def valid?(s)
    s.count('/') == 1
  end
  valid?('/this-is-not/fafa/fafa') # => false
  valid?('/balbabla') # => true
```

**UPDATE** (As per the @CasimiretHippolyte comment)

```
  def valid?(s)
    s.rindex('/') == 0
  end
  valid?('/this-is-not/fafa/fafa') # => false
  valid?('/balbabla') # => true
```

Comment: I'm not your downvoter but note that your function return valid for `blablabla/blablabla`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your feedback! but that's not a valid path too. And OP didn't mention that in the given examples too.all paths has to be started with at least one `/` as per the OP,which is to be considered as *valid*.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have updated as per your comment. please review.

Comment: you should combine the two conditions: `s.count('/')==1` and `s.rindex('/')==0`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why it needed? could you give me that lesson?

Comment: You are right, you don't need since it is the index of the last occurrence.